# Bootstrap input group segmented move elements

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML code (using [**Bootstrap 3**](http://getbootstrap.com/)) :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="text-info">Part title</h3>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">3</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info linkInterfaces" style="margin: 0 15px 0 15px !important"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">4</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this jQuery code :

```
$('.linkInterfaces').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-link')) {
        $(this).animate({'marginLeft': '10px', 'marginRight': '10px'}, 1000);
        $(this).find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-chain-broken');
    } else {
        $(this).animate({'marginLeft': '0', 'marginRight': '0'}, 1000);
        $(this).find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-link');
    }
});
```

I've made this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/avj7k3ku/) for you to understand better my problem.

How to ensure that the middle button never moves and if you click on it, those who are around move ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to animate the margins of the previous and next elements instead of the link element itself.

So instead of setting the margin on the central element, you set it on the elements next to it. You can then animate the margin of the previous element so that the margin is transferred from one side to the other, and remove the margin on the element next to the central element.

I updated your JSFiddle, [you can find it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ToJa92/avj7k3ku/1/)

Basically you would style the buttons like this instead:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" style="margin: 0 15px 0 0">3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info linkInterfaces"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" style="margin: 0 0 0 15px">4</button>
```

And then animate them like this (note the usage of `prev()` and `next()` which will get the previous and next sibling element, respectively):

```
$('.linkInterfaces').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-chain-broken')) {
        $(this).prev().animate({'marginRight': '0', 'marginLeft': '15px'}, 1000);
        $(this).next().animate({'marginLeft': '0'}, 1000);
        $(this).find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-link');
    } else {
        $(this).prev().animate({'marginRight': '15px', 'marginLeft': '0'}, 1000);
        $(this).next().animate({'marginLeft': '15px'}, 1000);
        $(this).find('i').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-chain-broken');
    }
});
```